# Select only distinct 'names' and order them by their 'newest date'

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I use a MySQL database to manage donations for an organisation. Donators can make more than one donations. Thus I have two tables: `donators` contains information about the donators and `donations` contains information about time and amount of the donations. Both tables are connected via a `donatorID`.

I want to read out information about each distinct donator. The list should be ordered by the date of the last donation. I came up with the code below, but that uses the date of the first donation instead of the last donation.

How can I use the newest donation-date for each donator?

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(`donators`.`name`),
    `donators`.`city`,
    `donators`.`country`,
    `donators`.`website`
FROM
    `donators`
INNER JOIN
    `donations`
ON
    `donators`.`donatorID` = `donations`.`donatorID`
ORDER BY `donations`.`date` DESC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.max_DATE
FROM    Donators a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DonatorID, MAX(date) max_DATE
            FROM    Donations
            GROUP   BY DonatorID
        ) b ON a.DonatorID = b.DonatorID
ORDER   BY  b.max_DATE DESC
```

if you want to have the records of `donation` table displayed based on the latest donation date,

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    Donators a
        INNER JOIN Donations c
            ON a.DonatorID = c.DonatorID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DonatorID, MAX(date) max_DATE
            FROM    Donations
            GROUP   BY DonatorID
        ) b ON  c.DonatorID = b.DonatorID AND
                c.date = b.max_DATE
ORDER   BY c.date DESC
```

Comment: JW's second solution seems like the most comprehensive to me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not interested in the individual values from the `donations` table, you can use this query:

```
SELECT
    `donators`.`name`,
    `donators`.`city`,
    `donators`.`country`,
    `donators`.`website`,
    MAX(`donations`.`date`) AS LastDate
FROM `donators`
INNER JOIN `donations` ON `donators`.`donatorID` = `donations`.`donatorID`
GROUP BY 
    `donators`.`name`,
    `donators`.`city`,
    `donators`.`country`,
    `donators`.`website`
ORDER BY
    LastDate DESC
```

Comment: I think JW's way is faster, since you first generate huge joined dataset, and than execute the GROUP BY. JW keeps the joined data swall, with using a subselect.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    who.name
    , who.city
    , who.country
    , who.website
    , what.thedate
FROM donators who
JOIN donations what ON what.donatorID = who.donatorID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM donations nx  
        WHERE nx.donatorID = what.donatorID
        AND nx.thedate > what.thedate
        )
ORDER BY what.thedate DESC
        ;
```

Comment: Nice way to put the commas :-). I'll adopt that.